# Similar functionality for java to struct for python

Tags: java, python, image, tiff

I have a program that I made in Python to find specific tags in TIFF IFD's and return the values. It was just a proof of concept thing in python, and now I need to move the functionality to java. I think I can just use the `String(byteArray[])` constructor for the ASCII data types, but I still need to get `Unsigned short (2 byte)` and `unsigned long (4 byte)` values. I don't need to write them back to the file or modify them, all I need to do is get a Java `Integer` or `Long` object from them. This is easy in python with the `struct` and `mmap` classes, does any one know of a similar way in java? I looked at the `DataInput` class, but the `readUnsignedLong` method reads 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) allows you to read shorts and longs.  You should mask them with the appropriate bit mask (`0xFFFF` for short, `0xFFFFFFFF` for 32 bit) in order to account for the difference between signed/unsigned types.

e.g.

```
// omits error handling
FileInputStream fis = ...;
DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(fis);
int short_value = 0xFFFF & stream.readShort();
long long_value = 0xFFFFFFFF & stream.readInt();
```

If you're sure that the data won't be towards the high end of the 2 byte field, or 4 byte field, you can forego the bit masking.  Otherwise, you need to use a wider data type to account for the fact that unsigned values hold a larger range of values than their signed counterparts.

Comment: @Much I started working on this finally and the value I am getting back for a short is `10752` When I know that the value of those 2 bytes is in fact `42` Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, apparently the byte order is opposite what struct in python led me to believe. That is going to complicated things badly

Comment: @keepitreall89 If you read the datastream into a java.nio.ByteBuffer somehow, you can specify the endianness of the bytebuffer and go from there.

Comment: I ended up using the RandomAccessFile (because I needed to jump to offsets a lot) class instead of FIS, and based on the javadoc for that class just reversed the order in how it computes longs and ints.

Answer (score 2):

> I looked at the DataInput class, but the `readUnsignedLong` method reads 8 bytes.

Java does not have unsigned types. It takes 4 bytes to make an `int`, and 8 bytes to make a `long`, unsigned or otherwise.

---

If you don't want to use `DataInput`, you can read the bytes into byte arrays (`byte[]`) and use a [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to turn those byte values into `int`s and `long`s with left padding. See [`ByteBuffer#getInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28%29) and [`ByteBuffer#getLong()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getLong%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

DataInput would be the preferred method.  You can use readUnsignedShort for the two byte values.  For the 4 byte values you'll have to use this [workaround](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4077352)...

```
long l = dis.readInt() & 0xffffffffL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Javolution's [Struct](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html) class which provides structure to regions of data. You set up a wrapper and then use the wrapper to access the data. Simples. Java really needs this super-useful class in its default classpath TBQH.

Answer (score 1):

[Preon Library](http://preon.codehaus.org/) is good to create struct in Java. I have tried  Javolution's Struct but it was not help full my case. It is open source and very good library.